# How do I put the different data into one cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is the sample data that I've got

| id | program | Community ID | sdg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 246 | #NoWasteGiving2020 | 97 | 11 |
| 246 | #NoWasteGiving2020 | 97 | 17 |
| 246 | #NoWasteGiving2020 | 97 | 10 |

With the data on the table above, how do I get the data to just be shown in one row and the sdg shown in one row. so at the end of the day the data will look like this:

```
246   #NoWasteGiving2020  97  10,11,17
```

This is the query that I've wrote

```
select Distinct a.id, a.title as program, b.community_id, c.goal_id as sdg
from programs_program as a
join associates_programcommunity as b on a.id = b.program_id
join associates_communitygoal as c on b.community_id = c.community_id
```

Comment: If this is a SQL question, at least share the SQL query you are using.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using

Comment: Please don't use an image for data, show us as formatted text.

Comment: Please, provide the sample data and desired output. It is not clear what should be done, because by specifying `column_name as sdg` you already have them in one row.

Comment: i tried using the string_agg function but it gave me this error message

function array_agg(integer, unknown) does not exist LINE 1: select a.id, a.title as program, b.community_id, array_agg(c... ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: got it working. I needed to do this:

string_agg(c.goal_id::character varying, ', ') as sdg. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string_agg` as follows:

```
select a.id, a.title as program, b.community_id, string_agg(c.goal_id, ',') as sdg
from programs_program as a
join associates_programcommunity as b on a.id = b.program_id
join associates_communitygoal as c on b.community_id = c.community_id
group by a.id, a.title, b.community_id
```

Comment: thanks popeye. I needed to add the character varying bit
~~~
string_agg(c.goal_id::character varying, ', ') as sdg
~~~

Comment: @KennardyKusuma . . . You have tagged the question SQL Server and the code in your comment would not work in SQL Server.